# Laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException if request has base64 image data

Tags: laravel, post, request, base64, http-post

I've a problem when I'm sending HTTP request containing base64 image data it throws " MethodNotAllowedHttpException ", but if the request doesn't contain a base64 data it works fine.
PS: the same request works on my localhost, but not working on my shared web hosting.

example of the request :

https://prnt.sc/jjybgw

Comment: I've found the solution . it's not a laravel problem i've turned off mod_secuity my shared hosting –

Answer (score 0):

It's problem of the post request method.

when you send the get request and route define of post request. Than occurred this issue

First check your form request URL

And also check in web.php

Route::get()

Or

Route::post()

Comment: hey, it's not a laravel problem.  I've found the solution, i've turned off mod_secuity my shared hosting